# SIGSTOPping a rsync

Tags: rsync

As far as I understood it, when I send SIGSTOP to a process it will not get scheduled from this point on, but the network stack keeps operating.

Will the rsync server try to reach the client and timeout on a query when the client is SIGSTOPped?

I don't know if that is standard nomenclature but I refer to the source server to which I input `rsync -opts localfiles... remote:dir` as the client, and the server that will receive the data as the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual says

> --timeout=TIMEOUT
>
> This option allows you to set a maximum I/O timeout in seconds. If no data is transferred for the specified time then rsync will exit. The default is 0, which means no timeout.

So the server should not timeout unless you specify a timeout. But your connection may time out due to other reasons, especially if you are behind a NAT, and it will certainly break if you have a dynamic IP and it changes.

Comment: Thanks. I have static IPs on all servers. And what I read about SIGSTOP lets me think that the TCP connection won't time out. So I guess it will work.